# Adds/change columns to table by spliting the last column by delimeter in sql, maintaining all columns from previous table?

Tags: split, proc-sql

Could anyone help me please?

I have this table. The column ***t2.'pathjv1'n***

```
PROC SQL;

Create table 'Shopping Report Bebe'n as
Select distinct
t1.'Campaign'n,
t1.'Day'n,
t1.'Cost'n as 'Investimento'n,
t1.'Impressions'n,
t1.'Clicks'n,
t1.'CTR'n,
t1.'Avg. CPC'n,
t1.'Conversions'n,
t1.'Conv. value'n,
t1.'Conv. value / cost'n,
t2.'codigo web'n,
t2.'descripción web'n as 'Product'n,
t2.'marcamostradaenweb'n as 'Brand'n,
t2.'path jv1'n

From  work.'Bebe'n as T1

left JOIN work.feed as T2
    ON t1.'Item ID'n = t2.'_col1'n

Group by 1,2;
```

The column t2.'pathjv1'n

```
t2.'pathjv1'n
----------------------------------------   
John > Doe Doe > Writer
Jane > Doe > Chemical Engineer > Sovena
```

I want to my final result to look like all the columns from the **Shopping Report Bebe** plus changing the ***t2.'pathjv1'n*** column as shown above.

```
t2.'pathjv1'n     Column2      Column3            Column4 
--------------------------------------------------
John             Doe Doe      Writer    
Jane             Doe          Chemical Engineer    Sovena
```

I need this in SQL, split by `>` - could you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably `proc sql`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using SAS Entrepise Guide 9.15, and the code with proc sql. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

In this first step just select the columns that you need to create the new table from your data source

```
PROC SQL;

Create table 'Shopping Report Bebe'n as
Select
t1.'Campaign'n,
t1.'Month'n,
t1.'Cost'n as 'Investimento'n,
t1.'Impressions'n,
t1.'Clicks'n,
t1.'CTR'n,
t1.'Avg. CPC'n,
t1.'Conversions'n,
t1.'Conv. value'n,
t1.'Conv. value / cost'n,
t2.'codigo web'n,
t2.'descripción web'n as 'Product'n,
t2.'marcamostradaenweb'n as 'Brand'n,
t2.'path jv1'n as Path

From  work.'Bebe'n as T1

left JOIN work.feed as T2
    ON t1.'Item ID'n = t2.'_col1'n

Group by 1,2;
    
QUIT;
```

Here is simple left join to cross the information i need from the second table t2 to be in the first table

In this step i used SAS instead of Proc SQL. The reason why is that while researching it was the only method i found that was usefull for my needs, that where to divide the last columns by a delimeter

At first you need to create the new columns and set the delimeter that you want

```
data 'shopping report bebe'n;
   set 'shopping report bebe'n;
   length var1-var4 $50.;
   array var(4) $;
   do i = 1 to dim(var);
      var[i]=scan(Path,i,'>');
   end;
run;
```

In this step i just removed the blank spaces and the numbers

```
data 'shopping report bebe'n;
set 'shopping report bebe'n;
var1 = compress(var1, '', 'd');
var2 = compress(var2, '', 'd');
var3 = compress(var3, '', 'd');
var4 = compress(var4, '', 'd');

run;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.